# EF returns 0000-0000-0000-xxx as Guid when I try save a new record or update existing record?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, identity-column

I am using EF4 in my C# project. The problem I'm faced with is that, when I try to save a record, I get a Primary Key Violation and the PK value is "0000-0000-0000-xxx". From my guess, EF does not recognize the IsIdentity flag and generate a guid value. In my SQL Server database for my table, I specify a PK(uniqueidentifier>guid) and also set it as the IdentityColumn, thus I would expect this to travel through to my project as such since the guid is generated in SQL Server. Is there a way to overcome this bug?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must specify your `Guid` ID as an Identity in your EF model. In EF 4.1:

```
[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }
```

(`Guid` Ids are not identities by default, in contrast to `int` Ids.)
If you create the database with this model EF will create a column with a default value of `newid()`.

In EF 4.0 you can go to the model designer, mark your Id property in the designer, open the properties window and then set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Identity`.

Comment: Thanks for your information. setting the storegeneratedpattern fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
```

Try this:

```
private System.Guid _id;
public System.Guid ID
{
    get
    {
        if (_id == null || _id == Guid.Empty)
            _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        return _id;
    }
    set
    {
        _id = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `_id` can never be `null` because it is a value type. The only value type that can be compared against null is `Nullable<T>`.