# EF 4.1 CodeFirst with Guid (not generated by DB/Store) as PK

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I'd like to create a model with a 'client generated' GUID as the primary key. I want the Guid to be auto-generated, but NOT on the DB, so I know the ID before I persist it, important for my domain model.

How do I setup:

```
class MyEntity {
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

So I can do...

```
 var newEntity = new MyEntity();
 transmitIDBeforePersisting(newEntity.ID);
 context.MyEntities.Add(newEntity);
 context.SaveChanges()
```

How can I setup MyEntity.ID so it is auto-generated when I call new, but still works properly as a Primary Key, with nav properties, etc?

This is similar to [using Guid as PK with EF4 Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270721/using-guid-as-pk-with-ef4-code-first), but NOT generated by the Store/DB.

Comment: Perhaps this answer from just 5 hours ago is helpful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174065/ef-returns-0000-0000-0000-xxx-as-guid-when-i-try-save-a-new-record-or-update-exis/7179259#7179259

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the value of the `ID` property in your constructor, and use the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` attribute on the `ID` property:

```
public class MyEntity 
{        
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public MyEntity()
    {
        ID = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Comment: @seth You might also need to use the `[Key]` attribute as well.

Comment: For EF fluent API see this: http://dailywebtips.blogspot.com/2012/09/entity-framework-5-auto-generated-guid.html